# How do I convert this ListView into Kotlin

Tags: java, android, listview, kotlin

This is my Listview in Kotlin but I want to change textsize and color,

```
    //Listview of Centers
    val regioncenters = resources.getStringArray(R.array.centers_list)
    var lv = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.center_content_lview)
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regioncenters)
    lv.adapter = adapter
```

so I search for this code but its suggestion that it is in Java and I want a clean Kotlin on my code

```
 center_content_lview.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_text, R.id.listview_style, regioncenters))
```

This code is working but in the future I want my code to be Kotlin.

Comment: You already have an array adapter you just need to change its parameters isn't it?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to programming.

Comment: No issues, no need to be sorry. I am glad to know and welcome to the world hope you are having a great time writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin You can write like this -

center_content_lview.adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.listview_text, R.id.listview_style, regioncenters)

is this the same you are expecting?

Comment: If you are new to kotlin and want to convert any java code to kotlin then you can use this https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt